# iptables not allowing ssh

Tags: networking, ssh, iptables

This is my iptable configuration. But I cannot connect with ssh with these rules. What am I doing wrong? I want to block all traffic except ssh coming from x.x.x.x ip address.

```
iptables -F
iptables -X

iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s x.x.x.x --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP
```

iptables -L output

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     tcp  --  x.x.x.x        anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh state NEW,ESTABLISHED
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Comment: Are you setting default OUTPUT policy for your NIC to DROP ?

Comment: No I have not, Should I?

Comment: No, surely not. Are you sure that it doesn't work ? I think it's just slow because you don't filter by states so iptables has to filter every single packet, what if you change your rule to append `-m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED` after the `dport 22` ? If it still doesn't work, post your full `iptables -nvL` output.

Comment: added iptables -L output to post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably missed to post a part of your configuration as you have :

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
```

So all your default policies are **DROP**.

You are dropping all output traffic going through your NIC by default ...

```
/sbin/iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp -d x.x.x.x --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```